# Does the assignment operator in c# take any other value other than bool in any scenario?

Tags: c#, if-statement, assignment-operator

I recently started learning c# and got to know that the if condition takes only the boolean value for the assignment operator like in the below code. But I wanted to know if there is any scenario where if takes any value other than bool.

I tried changing the type of 'a' to char but it gave me a compile time error.

```
Console.Write("Enter a character: ");
char c = (char)Console.Read();
bool a;
if (a=Char.IsLetter(c))
{
    if (a=Char.IsLower(c))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The character is lowercase.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The character is uppercase.");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a character");
}
```

Comment: you don't need variable `a` at all... You just need to do `if(Char.IsLetter(c))`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yeah that 'a' i placed to see if i can give it as a char variable and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sometimes have used an expression like this:-

```
string a = null;

    if((a = GetValue()) != null){
    DoSomething();
    }
```

It is a nice syntax to assign other values other than null and check it for a boolean expression. Although keep in mind that the outermost bracket will always ask for a boolean expression.

Answer (score 1):

> But I wanted to know if there is any scenario where if takes any value
>   other than bool.

No, no and sort of

[if-else (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else)

> An if statement identifies which statement to run based on the value
>   of a **Boolean expressio**n

The following only works because the result is a boolean value

```
if (a=Char.IsLower(c))
```

it is equivalent to

```
a=Char.IsLower(c);
if (a)
```

The same as the following `a` and `b` become the result `Char.IsLower(c)`

```
bool a = false;
bool b = false; 
a = b = Char.IsLower(c)
```

... The result must equate to bool (end of story)

The caveat (if you want to call it that) is nullable and *Lifted Operators*. Lifted operators are operators which work over nullable types by "lifting" the operators which already exist on the non-nullable form, however its still must equate to a boolean expression.

```
?int bob = null

if(bob > 3) { ... }
```

---

**Additional Resources**

From the [C# specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf)

> **12.4.8 Lifted operators**
>
> - For the equality operators `== !=`
>
>   - a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool. The lifted
>       form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each operand
>       type. The lifted operator considers two null values equal, and a null
>       value unequal to any non-null value. If both operand are non-null, the
>       lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying
>       operator to produce the bool result.
> - For the relational operators `< > <= >=`
>
>   - a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool. The lifted
>       form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each operand
>       type. The lifted operator produces the value false if one or both
>       operands are null. Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operands
>       and applies the underlying operator to produce the bool result.